# Rewrite an URL but keep the original one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to keep the original URL from my subdomain to a specific page :

I tried the following but not working :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/page1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

I get  : http://domain.com/page1/

I want : http://my-subdomain.domain.com

Comment: Your question is unclear: obviously you will get `http://domain.com/page1/` with that rewriting rule. You explicitly rewrite to that.

Comment: I want to keep the original URL : http://my-subdomain.domain.com

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be elitist or anything. It is just that it is not clear what you are trying to do. I suggest you use the `edit` button below your question and add more details: what is it you want to do. not in technical terms, but from a users point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-subdomain.domain.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Input

```
http://domain.com/page1/
```

Output

```
http://my-subdomain.domain.com/
```